# Creating classes that can be instantiated with single or multiple elements as constructor's argument in Scala

Tags: scala, collections

I want to have class that can be instantiated with list, array, seq, set, stack, queue etc.
In my opinion

```
class A
class B(elems:A*)
```

should handle such stuff.

This is my solution:

```
class A
class B(elems:Iterable[A]){
    def this(elem:A) = this(Seq(elem))
}
```

Can you suggest any improvements?

Comment: Doesn't:

 class B(elems: A*) 

do the trick?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any Seq or Array may be passed to a method with repeated parameters by using the `: _*` ascription:

```
scala> def m1(strs: String*): Int = { strs.foldLeft(0)(_ + _.length) }
m1: (strs: String*)Int

scala> m1("foo", "bar")
res0: Int = 6

scala> val ss1 = Array("hello", ", ", "world", ".")
ss1: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(hello, , , world, .)

scala> m1(ss1: _*)
res1: Int = 13

scala> val ss2 = List("now", "is", "the", "time")
ss2: List[java.lang.String] = List(now, is, the, time)

scala> m1(ss2: _*)
res2: Int = 12
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a minor improvement.

```
class A
class B(elems:Iterable[A]){
    def this(elem:A*) = this(elem.asInstanceOf[Iterable[A]])
}
```

That'll make these legal

```
val b1 = new B(a1)
val b2 = new B(a2, a3)
```

Comment: @Jeriho : yeah. I tested it with String in the REPL